# django_auth_ldap raises OPERATIONS_ERROR

Tags: django, ldap, django-authentication, python-ldap

I'm trying to build user authentication against our LDAP:

settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://********-dc01.*******.ru"

import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("cn=users,dc=*********,dc=ru",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,"(uid=%(user)s)")

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def project_list(request):
...
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name':'login.html'}),
```

and the template is [from this example](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#logging).

It will take me to auth form and I get the following debug output:

```
search_s('cn=users,dc=********,dc=ru', 2, '(uid=bolotnov)') raised OPERATIONS_ERROR({'info': '000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906DC, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db0', 'desc': 'Operations error'},)
search_s('cn=users,dc=**********,dc=ru', 2, '(uid=bolotnov)') raised OPERATIONS_ERROR({'info': '000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906DC, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db0', 'desc': 'Operations error'},)
Authentication failed for bolotnov
Authentication failed for bolotnov
```

I tried googling but haven't found anything that could help me moth further, perhaps a hint from community - maybe there is something simple I'm missing or a check to do? I seem able to anonym bind to our ldap via Softerra LDAP browser maybe ldap_auth_user_search should be somewhat different?

Comment: I think I know what the issue is but can't verify it yet. It will attempt to bind to the LDAP server for user's preferences using the same credentials the user has provided in the login/password field. What happens is - the user is happily found/validated with the login/password token BUT to bind to LDAP, the server is expecting the domain name is provided as well - and this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

although ldap_simple_bind_s() would return a successful bind, it's about referrals option that I had to disable to get that to work:

```
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the server, even if it is an anonymous bind.

therefore you must have real values of

```
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I can in this post ask another question.
In views.py I have something like this:

> def login(request):
>
> ```
> c = {}
> c.update(csrf(request))
> return render_to_response('login.html', c)
> ```
>
> def auth_view(request):
>
> username = request.POST.get('username', '')
>      password = request.POST.get('password', '')
>      user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
>
> if user is not None:
>          auth.login(request, user)
>          return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin')
>      else:
>          return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid')

My question is how can I bind it with ldap server?
In the django docs there is template for logging:

> import logging
>
> logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
>   logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
>   logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

But I don't know how to implement it in rhis code exactly

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've got it already in settings.py:

> AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://myldapadress"
>
> AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
>   AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
>   AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("my search configs",
>       ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "uid=uid")
>
> AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
>      'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
>      'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
>   )
>
> logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
>
> logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
>   logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

But my question was where and how I should implement ldap loggins so this funcktion in views.py would use it.
Sorry for any english mistakes and too generall questions